# Change User Input into the name of a List

Tags: python, list, input

I am making a program right now in python. To make the program efficient I was hoping there is a way to take user input and change it into the name of a list. Basically, like removing the quotes on it.

Like this `input = input("What is your name")`
Let's say your name is Ted.
I have a list that is `Ted = ["Blah, Blahh]`
So basically I want to convert the input which would be "Ted", to just be Ted.

Comment: If you have to, why not use a dictionary? {'Ted': [Blah, Blahh]}

Comment: Python version is 3.x I suppose?

Comment: Yes, use a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a dictionary instead:

```
dict_1 = {}
name = input("What is your name")
dict_1[name] = ["blah", "blah"]
```

Read more about dictionaries on Internet. You shouldn't use `input` as the name of a variable since it is a Python reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
lists = {
    "Ted": ["Blah", "Blahh"],
    "Joe": ["Foob", "zerx"],
}
name = input("What is your name? ")
if name not in lists:
    print("Don't have a list for that name")
else:
    print("The list is %s" % (lists[name],))
```

Use `raw_input` instead of `input` if you're using Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is want you want:

```
globals()['ted'] = 42
print(ted)
```